# Can't find "Free Up Space" options in Settings on Samsung (Android 12) device

Tags: samsung, settings, storage, cleanup

For some reason, I'm unable to find the Free Up/Clean Up Space feature in Settings on my Samsung Android 12 ([specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxC7d.jpg)) phone.

[image: My Files]

My device has 60GB+ listed under Other in the Storage menu that I would like to clean up, but I don't see a way to do it without resorting to using 3rd-party apps. It feels like that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. I'm not sure One UI, which is Samsung's customization provides built-in "Free up space". Meanwhile, the "Free up space" on my Pixel device which links to [Google's own "Files" app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.files) instead (1st-party app for Pixel, 3rd-party app for others). Not sure about other manufacturers and their customization.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen a "free up space" option before on my phone.
I downloaded the Files app (by Google) and it's only reporting 76GB used out of 128. Then at the bottom of the Internal Storage screen (in the Google Files app) it says "Other: System - Couldn't calculate"

I'm considering removing pictures and videos and just Factory Resetting at this point, since the Samsung side of things is still showing 60GB+ taken up by "Other".

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on each item such as Images or Videos. Then you can select the images or videos and delete.

Otherwise use a file manager or a system cleaning app.

Comment: I don't want to remove images or videos, I want to clean up the 60GB+ listed as Other under Storage settings. It's taking up about half of my storage space.

Anything shown as Other is apparently: private app data, failed backup services, failed OTA updates, hidden cache or temporary files.

I'm trying to avoid installing a random 3rd party app to do this, I would like to use the built-in storage clean-up functionality that is apparently missing from my phone.